# How to run Visual VM on remote centos

Tags: centos, java

We have a java application residing on centos machine. From our windows machine we plan to connect to the application. We have enabled  jstatd and confirmed is running. The issue now is visual vm can never see the application for profiling? Any help on this?

Comment: Are you seeing any errors? Have you turned off iptables on CentOS?

Comment: yes I have all already put the port under the ip tables n update it accordingly. The user name and password must be my ssh details rite? The error is cannot connect to root@myip using service:jmx:rmi://myip:1099/jmxrmi?

Answer (score 1):

JMX uses a lot of ports, and you'd typically have to tell the JVM to enable remote management.

Disable the firewall for all traffic from your ip and check your app is listening for JMX connections from the network.

Comment: While disabling your firewall temporarily can help to troubleshoot connectivity issues, be sure that you re-enable the firewall with a proper configuration if it has been identified as a culprit.